# TableView's insertRowsAtIndexPaths adds wrong name

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, tableview

I've got a weird problem, when I add new usernames to a tableView and insert it the following way (if I just simply reload the table data it doesn't happen), the names always "appear" the same as the username at index 0. When I switch views and come back to the tableView everything is ok, the new username changed it's name "back to its supposed name". Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the NSIndexPath? Hope someone can help. Thank you!

```
NSIndexPath *path1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
NSArray *indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:path1,nil];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArraywithRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert the row at the index path where the new name should be, not at row 0. So, if you did something like `[self.mutableNames insertObject:@"name" atIndex:4]` to add the name to your data, then you'd want to create the index path for the row you insert like `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0]`.

Comment: Thank you! But if i have no particular order in the list, how do I know where to add the entry?

Comment: @LinusAn you're welcome. How are you determining where to insert the username in now?

Comment: After the user entered the name and pressed ok, the name is assigned to a new core data entry and saved, then I update the array (which fetches the data base for its entries -> array = all db entries) which is the source for the table. then the insertRowsAtIndexPaths method is called. Maybe this is the totally wrong way?

Comment: @LinusAn Ah, I see. If you really do need to do a new fetch, then you could keep a pointer to the `NSManagedObject` around and get its index within the array and insert the row there. If you don't need to fetch again then I'd say just append (or prepend) the new object to your existing array, then insert the row at index `array.count - 1` (or 0, if you prepended). Make sense?